# Create a new Data time Column by combining separate Date and Time Column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with separate `Date` and `Time` columns. And I would like to combine both `Date` and `Time` into one `DateTime` Column.

I found a [similar thread](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Unify-Date-and-Time-columns-into-one-DateTime-column/td-p/25820) to combine using Power Query. But I can't see date and time table in edit query. Please help me with a calculated column to combine date and time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add them together assuming `Date` is a date data type and `Time` is a time data type.

```
DateTime = Dates[Date] + Dates[Time]
```

[image: Calculated Column]

Comment: Thanks! For me, `DateTime = DATE([Date]) + TIME([Time])` works fine with some RIGHT/LEFT as I have the format  YYMMDD HH:MM in one text column, e.g. 190301 03:00. Full example `DateTime = date("20"&left([Text],2),right(left([Text],4),2),right(left([Text],6),2)) + time(right(left([Text],9),2),0,0)`